# Angular Datatables not loading data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, typescript, datatable

I've been trying to use Datatables on my Angular application and for some reason when I get an array from a json service, the table loads before the data arrives, and the result I get is this: 
[image]

If I try to order the data, all of it vanishes.

This is my users-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './shared/user.service';
import { User } from "./shared/user";
var $ = require('jquery');
var dt = require('datatables.net')

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})



export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  public users: User[] = [];

  constructor(public userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(data => this.users = data);

    $('table').DataTable();
  }
}
```

and here's my html:

```
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="name">Nome</th>
      <th data-field="tg_ie">IE</th>
      <th data-field="cpf_cnpj">CPF</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let u of users">
      <td>{{ u.nome }}</td>
      <td>{{ u.rg_ie }}</td>
      <td>{{ u.cpf_cnpj }}</td>

      <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/users', u.id]">
          Editar
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a (click)="deleteUser(o)" href="">
          Deletar
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
  <a routerLink="new">
    Novo
  </a>
</div>
```

I have followed this guide to install the datatables: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started
my .angular-cli.json and app.module.js have those imports.

How am I able to load it right?

Thanks!
@Edit
this is my code listing the "users" using ruby on rails:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users
end
```

And this is how I call it on angular

```
private url: string = "http://localhost:3000/users";
getUsers() {
  return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching Synchronous and Asynchronous requests in your web service?

Comment: I've edited the question with how i'm using it, any idea of how I can make it   work properly?

Comment: Here is a tutorial, the right way to do it is using promises, http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/